# How to add the optimum threshold to the ROC curve plot in R

Tags: r, plot, roc, threshold

I got this example below and wondering how to get the optimal threshold (Youden's index = sensitivity+specificity-1) for each method and plot that value on the ROC curve to know the coordinate obtained from that optimal threshold. How to do that? My real ROC curves consist of 4 roc curves (see the example below) for four different methods and I want to plot the optimum threshold for each method on each corresponding method. For simplicity, I use the example below instead.

```
library(ROCR)
data(ROCR.simple)
df <- data.frame(ROCR.simple)
pred <- prediction(df$predictions, df$labels)
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","for")
plot(perf,colorize=FALSE)
```

This is an example of my ROC curve. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily with the pROC package (disclaimer: I am the author and maintainer of this package). Setting the `print.thres`

```
library(pROC)
my_curve <- roc(df$predictions, df$labels)
plot(my_curve, print.thres=TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, it is an awesome package but the thing is that I cannot use this package since I need to make my own to plot the ROC curve because the method I'm analysing is not a binary classifier but rather classify 10 different things.   The figure I showed is my own ROC curve, but the example I showed is a simple example to make it easy to reproduce.